# Как статически прилинковать sfml с помощью CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

Пытаюсь так:

```
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${SFML_DIR}/lib/cmake/SFML" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics window system)
target_link_libraries(Project_Name sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-window)
```

-- Говорит, что не может найти -lsfml-graphics, ...
Так:

```
target_link_libraries(Project_Name
    ${SFML_DIR}/lib/libsfml-graphics-s-d.a
    ${SFML_DIR}/lib/libsfml-window-s-d.a
    ${SFML_DIR}/lib/libsfml-system-s-d.a)
```

-- просто ничего не происходит...

Comment: `target_link_directories` забыто

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо! Теперь первый способ дает то же, что и второй: кучу undefined reference to...

Comment: всё, проблема решена. Оказалось я с версией компилятора немного напутал, а так всё правильно...